# 301 Redirect showthread.php?t=1&page=2 to threads/1/page-2?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect the following

`http://www.example.com/showthread.php?t=1&page=2` to `http://www.example.com/threads/1/page-2`

and

`http://www.example.com/showthread.php?t=1` to `http://www.example.com/threads/1`

I want to "301 Redirect" it NOT "Rewrite" i.e I want the "http://www.example.com/showthread.php?t=1&page=2" link to 301 redirect to folder structure.

Please advice?

Comment: What did you try, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+showthread\.php\?t=(\d+)&page=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /threads/%1/page-%2? [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+showthread\.php\?t=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /threads/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

# not for file or directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^threads/(\d+)/page-(\d+)/?$ /showthread.php?t=$1&page=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^threads/(\d+)/?$ /showthread.php?t=$1 [L,NC]
```